# Win32 API ListView Creation (C++)

Tags: c++, winapi, mingw, win32gui

I want to create a ListView in c++.
My code so far:

```
InitCommonControls(); // Force the common controls DLL to be loaded.
HWND list;

// window is a handle to my window that is already created.
list = CreateWindowEx(0, (LPCSTR) WC_LISTVIEWW, NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | LVS_SHOWSELALWAYS | LVS_REPORT, 0, 0, 250, 400, window, NULL, NULL, NULL);

LVCOLUMN lvc; 
lvc.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
lvc.iSubItem = 0;
lvc.pszText = "Title";
lvc.cx = 50;
lvc.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
ListView_InsertColumn(list, 0, &lvc);
```

But if I compile and execute the code, just a blank window is beeing showed. Compiler: MinGW on Windows 7 (x86).

Can anybody help me showing the listview properly?

Comment: The MSDN shows you everything you need to know.  Here's a starting point:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: sorry, the method in the link dosen't work :(

Comment: I suggest you do a little more digging int he MSDN, then.  That's how I figured out how to use a ListView, and it did work for me.

Comment: Note that there's [additional sample code available for creating a `ListView` on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2890/Using-ListView-control-under-Win-API)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the link to original MSDN sample code of [ListView control](http://csdata.iblogger.org/programming/CodeSamples/) written in Windows API and C. 
It compiles in VC++ 2010.

Comment: how do I change the style to windows 7 design?

Comment: What is "Windows 7 design" exactly?  Are you referring to visual themes?  You ned to provide a ComCtrl32 v6 manifest to enable that. Nothing in the code changes, unless you want to take advantage of new features introduced in ComCtrl32 v6.

Comment: @das_j You can add the following compiler directive to enable that:
 `#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"") `

Comment: Note that in Visual Studio 2013+ you will need to add `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and 
`#define _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE` to the top of LISTVIEW.C  to run this code as-is. Alternatively you could replace `sprintf` with `sprintf_s` and `strcmpi` with `_strcmpi`.

Answer (score 5):

`WC_LISTVIEWW` (notice the extra W on the end) is a `wchar_t*`, but you are type-casting it to a `char*`.  That will only compile if `UNICODE` is not defined, making the generic `CreateWindowEx()` map to `CreateWindowExA()`.  Which means you are trying to create a Unicode window with the Ansi version of `CreateWindowEx()`.  That will not work.

You need to either:

1. use the generic `WC_LISTVIEW` so it matches the generic `CreateWindowEx`(), and get rid of the type-cast:

   ```
   list = CreateWindowEx(..., WC_LISTVIEW, ...);
   ```
2. keep using `WC_LISTVIEWW`, but call `CreateWindowExW()` instead:

   ```
   list = CreateWindowExW(..., WC_LISTVIEWW, ...);
   ```